# HKQueryOptions in predicate

Tags: swift, healthkit, hksamplequery

I am trying to use a predicate to take the data from the last 30 days from HealthKit. Many of the tutorials online use `.None` as their `HKQueryOption`, and as I am unfamiliar with HKQueryOptions, I was wondering if anyone else knew what could replace `.None` in this instance. Currently, I have put in `.None` as the `HKQueryOptions` but this causes my error. 
`'None' is unavailable: use [] to construct an empty option set`
When I put in `[]` instead, and print `results` it comes back as `[]`

Here is my query function where I declare the predicate

```
let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose)
        let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options:.None)
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType!, predicate: mostRecentPredicate, limit: 35, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, results, error) in
```

Comment: Please add the error in your question

Comment: I added the error and what I tried after that @DatNguyen

Comment: I'm no expert in this subject matter, but when you use `[]`, see no error, and get back `[]`, it means: 1) The query is in correct format; and 2) Empty result means that there's no matched result for your query. Why did you get empty result? Maybe there's no data in your HealthKit in the last 30 days. Maybe there's no data at all. You'll need to figure this out yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the empty set literal `[]` instead of `.None`:

```
let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end:endDate, options:[])
```

Comment: when i try this and print results from my query it comes back as `[]`